# Connecting JSch Channel InputStream to a JTextField box, commands not being sent

Tags: java, jframe, inputstream, outputstream, jsch

I'm trying to build a Jframe based SSH client. I've got the client connected, and the outputstream piped to a JTextArea.

The problem lies in user input, taken from a JTextField below the JTextArea, read when the user pressed enter and sent to the server.

```
public class InputArea extends InputStream {

byte[] contents;
int pointer = 0;


public InputArea(JTextField inputarea) {

    TextPrompt consoleTp = new TextPrompt(">> ", inputarea);
    consoleTp.setShow(TextPrompt.Show.FOCUS_LOST);
    inputarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560, 40));
    inputarea.setVisible(true);
    // Fire listener for input area when enter key is pressed .
    inputarea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == '\n') {
                contents = inputarea.getText().getBytes();
                pointer = 0;
                inputarea.setText("");
            }
            super.keyReleased(e);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    if (pointer >= contents.length) return -1;
    return this.contents[pointer++];
}
```

}

This class extends InputStream, and listens on the user pressing the enter key. From there it reads the contents of the JTextField, and (hopefully) sets this to 'contents', which is read by the InputStream when not blank.

From there, in the main JFrame class for the console window;

```
    //
    // Configure input area
    //
    JTextField inputTextField = new JTextField();
    in = new InputArea(inputTextField);
    add(inputTextField);
```

And then in the method connecting to the SSH server;

Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);

```
        // Disable key checking
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.setPassword(String.valueOf(password));
        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + host + " on port " + port + " ....");
        session.connect(3000);


        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setInputStream(in);
        channel.setOutputStream(out);
        channel.connect(3000);
        System.out.println("Connected.");
```

The output stream for the server functions fine (see screenshots below) and when a command is entered and the return key pressed, the TextField resets its contents. However this command is not sent to the server (tested by running mkdir Testing ect).

Any advice would be appreciated. If you want the full code sample it can be found at https://github.com/ElliotAlexander/SSH-Connect-GUI.

[The connected terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM9A4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The commands you send to the remote server are not executed because they are not terminated by a newline character.

Your code only sends the text of the input field, but the newline character gets "swallowed up" by your code. To fix this, just append a newline character to the byte buffer. Additionally, I think the way you extend the InputStream class is causing some issues, because the read method is only called once by the Jsch channel.

I would recommend using a pair of piped streams object instead. You would need to initialize them in ConsoleWindow and pass them to the InputArea and channel:

```
private PipedInputStream pin;
private PipedOutputStream pout;

public ConsoleWindow(...) {
    pin = new PipedInputStream();
    pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);
    // InputArea no longer needs to extend InputStream
    in = new InputArea(inputTextField, pout);
    ...
}

private void SSHConnect() {
     ...
     channel.setInputStream(pin);
     ...
}
```

Finally, write your commands the output stream:

```
public InputArea(final JTextField inputarea, final PipedOutputStream pout) {
    ...
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == '\n') {
            byte[] tmp = inputarea.getText().getBytes();
            pout.write(tmp, 0, tmp.length);
            pout.write('\n');
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference, the commands still aren't reaching the server.