# Run Commands continuously and step by step based on previous command output in JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

i want to implement a thing in my application works like putty or mobaxterm.i want user ssh to server then run commands and do things on that.i used ChannelExec but after run any command it would disconnect channel and went to first step.for example i want to run ls then return result to user then user cd into one directory and then run ls and see what is inside that directory.
how should implement this?

Comment: See [JSch - execute shell and interact with the execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45487797/850848) and also [Connecting JSch Channel InputStream to a JTextField box, commands not being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38725961/850848).

Comment: i have seen them before.they didnt help me.answers are not helpful.but thanks @MartinPrikryl

Comment: And where does your question say, that you have tried something already and why it did not help you specifically? *"Answers are not helpful"* does not tell us anything. + If nothing else, the linked questions should at least make it clear that you should use "shell" channel and not "exec".

Comment: i used shell channel before.shell channell didnt execute my command and didnt returned response of command,realy i got confuse about it,exec execute the command but didnt save state and shell just add my command to server and didnt execute it @Martin prikryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 1 month struggling with code and documentation i've found the answer.

i wanted to implement the ssh in enterprise application.first of all i have to say if you want interactive behavior you should use "shell" because it can give your command and return answer and stay connect with server but "exec" after execute command close channel.then i defined output and input as class variables.this is my class:

@Service
public class SshService {

```
private Channel channel;
private Session session;
ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PipedInputStream pip = new PipedInputStream(40);
PipedOutputStream pop = new PipedOutputStream(pip);
PrintStream print = new PrintStream(pop);

public SshService() throws IOException {
}

public String sshConnectToOlt(String username, String password, String host, int port) throws Exception {

    session = new JSch().getSession(username, host, port);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect(30000);

    channel = session.openChannel("shell");

    channel.setInputStream(pip);

    responseStream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);

    channel.connect(3 * 1000);

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    return responseStream.toString();

}

public String sshToOltCommands(String command) throws Exception {
    print.println(command);

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    String response = responseStream.toString();
    return response.replaceAll("\u001B\\[[\\d;]*[^\\d;]","");
}

public void disconnectFromOlt() {
    this.channel.disconnect();
    this.session.disconnect();
}
```

}

i write 3  methods.
sshConnectToOlt: for connecting to server
sshToOltCommands : executes command on server
disconnectFromOlt : disconnect from server

**NOTICE**:

i used

```
response.replaceAll("\u001B\\[[\\d;]*[^\\d;]","");
```

to remove ANSI control chars (VT100) from response